# Save only clipping areas of canvas in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to save a canvas as image [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-render-to-bitmap-dd4f549f) code

My Canvas height and width is 500,500 and its clipping coordinates are also 500,500

```
 <Canvas x:Name="DrawCanvas"  Width="500" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="500" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="DrawCanvas_Tapped">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,500,500"></RectangleGeometry>
            </Canvas.Clip>
        </Canvas>
```

but when I add image as children whose height and width is 600,600 and then saved it Canvas also save that part also by covering the extra space with black color and then save it . How to resolve this, I want that only that part is saved that is visible to the users.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my self by using this xaml code .I make another canvas parent of DrawCanvas and save that

```
<Canvas x:Name="Rect" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="{x:Null}">

            <Canvas x:Name="DrawCanvas" Width="500" Height="500" Background="White">
                <Image x:Name="MyImg" Tapped="MyImg_Tapped" ManipulationDelta="MyImg_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,Scale" Width="200" Height="200" Source="Assets/8.png">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>

            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
```

And Save only the rect Canvas it gives only the image which use are seeing.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

By default canvas do no clip its child so you may need to enable the same

so set `ClipToBounds="True"` in your canvas

eg.

```
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="DrawCanvas" Width="500" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="500" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="DrawCanvas_Tapped">
        <Canvas.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,500,500"></RectangleGeometry>
        </Canvas.Clip>
    </Canvas>
```

if the above approach is not sufficient enough for your case then you may perhaps need to do the layout of the canvas before rendering to image

```
    c.Measure(new Size(500, 500));
    c.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500));
```

above may only be necessary if you are creating canvas in your code only, not as a element in visual tree of your window or other container.

Comment: Are u understood what I am trying to do?

Comment: No clipbounds property

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a working sample? that will help me give you accurate answer. I understand that you just want to save the image of clip region from canvas.

Comment: please give me your email

Comment: here it is on msdn.I have posted here also                                                         http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/11f98e97-40de-4df9-8c7b-1997414789df/canvas-saving-problem-after-scaling-children-element?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: `ClipToBounds` is not available in WinRT/XAML. You need to manually set the Clip rect on size changes.

Comment: I have done that sir please see above question on msdn.

Comment: Please share your entire project with a sample image. Looking briefly over just the pieces you shared - everything seems fine.

Comment: Sir please see these image                                               https://comicmakerapp.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=1NA0vEYBAAA.bC11x-IsEVKMfKB2j0RdBw.2tfyB4SbME11y7WnzebVng&postId=1963787340665028370&type=POST

Comment: Sir here is the sample                                                    https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FF57BAE90AC42267!2102

Comment: tap on image to make its opacity 0.5 then scale again tap to make its opacity 1 for translating

Comment: just make image scale outside and save it you will see error.

Answer (score 0):

please make parent canvas for DrawCanvas:

```
        <Canvas x:Name="DrawCanvas" Width="500" Height="500" Background="White">
            <Image x:Name="MyImg" Tapped="MyImg_Tapped" ManipulationDelta="MyImg_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,Scale" Width="200" Height="200" Source="Assets/8.png">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>

        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

hopes thiswill work for you

Comment: I have answered above